# How to link to a CSS if a certain condition happens?

Tags: javascript, css, html, hyperlink

I have two CSS pages,

I want to link the HTML page to one of them depending on certain conditions.

How to do it?

Comment: What conditions? Are you using PHP or just HTML5 & JS?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can dynamically create the `<link>` element with JavaScript:

```
var link = document.createElement('link');

link.rel = 'stylesheet';
link.type = 'text/css';
link.href = 'css1.css';

document.head.appendChild(link);
```

Or just edit the `href` attribute of an existing one:

```
document.getElementById('your_stylesheet').href = 'css1.css';
```

And give your `<link>` element an `id`:

```
<link href="default.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" id="your_stylesheet" />
```

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at [this page](http://www.thesitewizard.com/javascripts/change-style-sheets.shtml) that explains how to use JS to switch style-sheets. This is only possible if the 'conditions' are ones that you can detect client-side.

Answer (score 0):

### old IE conditionals

There are some old conditionals for IE

```
<!--[if lte IE 6]>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/css/ie6_fix.css" />
<![endif]-->
<!--[if IE 7]>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/css/ie7_fix.css" />
<![endif]-->
```

### new media queries

There are some new media queries:
    `<link rel='stylesheet' media='screen and (min-width: 701px) and (max-width: 900px)' href='css/medium.css' />`

http://css-tricks.com/css-media-queries/

### javascript

Use javascript to load css.  Something like this:
http://www.javascriptkit.com/javatutors/loadjavascriptcss.shtml