# How to only apply the stylesheet if class is present on the page?

Tags: javascript, css, jscript

I am using the following script to apply the stylesheet only if the class .item-label is not present on the page. I does not seem to work. Any ideas where my script is wrong? It seems the script is ignoring the class: .badge-icon icon-template... It doesn't matter if it is present or isn't present. I have the script loading at the bottom of the page.

```
<script>
if(!document.querySelector('..badge-icon icon-template')){
    var link_el = document.createElement('link');
    link_el.rel = 'stylesheet';
    link_el.href = 'https://sub.domain.com/tester1.css';
    document.head.appendChild(link_el);
}

</script>
```

Comment: Where's the script deployed? Is it before the DOM has loaded or after?

Comment: At the very end of </body>

Comment: `only if the class .item-label is not present` ... but your code doesn't look for that .... you also have a typo in the selector `..badge-icon` unless the class actually IS `.badge-icon` ... i.e. you have something like `<sometag class=".badge-icon"> ... <icon-template> ... </icon-template> ... </sometag>`

Comment: by the way, according to specs, a class name can not start with `.`

Comment: Sorry this is the element: <i class="badge-icon icon-template"></i>.. the .. is an typo on my end for when I was typing out the post.

Comment: I think the issue is the class name. If I use an ID "#element" it works. But if I try a class with or without the "." it does not find it. Any thoughts?

Answer (score 0):

So,

it seems superfluous to remind you that there may be infinite reasons why your code, apparently correct, does not work.

Assuming that **your page does not contain errors** in the **HTML**, or in some **script**, there could be two potential causes:

Your script is **executed before the document is loaded**, or the css file is **not downloaded as it is already in the browser cache** or all things.

try adding this script and then if the problem persists could you add the browser console output to the question?

```
<script>
    document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function(){

    if(!document.querySelector('.badge-icon icon-template')){
        var noCache = '?' + new Date().getTime(); // add timestamp to url to force file upload 
        var link_el = document.createElement('link');
        link_el.rel = 'stylesheet';
        link_el.href = 'https://sub.domain.com/tester1.css' + noCache;
        document.head.appendChild(link_el);
    }
});
</script>
```

Answer (score -1):

**Just Add type also:**

```
   var link_el = document.createElement('link');    
        link_el.rel = 'stylesheet';
        link_el.type = 'text/css';
        link_el.href = 'tester1.css';
        document.head.appendChild(link_el);
```

[Check it here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14019167/how-to-link-to-a-css-if-a-certain-condition-happens)

Comment: read [link documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/link) ... *given that CSS is the only stylesheet language used on the web, not only is it possible to omit the type attribute, but is actually now recommended practice* - so, no, you don't need to add `type` attribute, in fact you **should not**

Answer (score -2):

Just put your code just before the ending `</body>` tag this should ensure the document is loaded

```html
<script>
   // DOM available
</script>
</body>
```

Comment: *the script loading at the bottom of the page* - an IIFE isn't going to change anything